# Fresh Blazor Server App in Visual Studio doesn't work on a Win11 VirtualBox VM under Arch Linux

Tags: c#, .net, linux, blazor, virtual-machine

I'm trying to set up a .NET 6 Blazor Server Project using Visual Studio 2022, because I want to get into developing .NET Maui applications which also support a web Frontend. So I'm starting with the part I'm more familiar with first.

Since Visual Studio isn't available for Linux I'm running all of this in a [Win11 VM provided by Microsoft](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/virtual-machines/) because we have a similar setup at work (only difference is that it's a Win11 VM in a Win10 Environment).

My problem is that the standard Blazor Server project gets stuck right at startup when I try to run it. This is the script that is used for the main program:

```cs
using FirstBlazorApp.Data;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<WeatherForecastService>();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.MapBlazorHub();
app.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");

app.Run();
```

When I set a breakpoint the last line that gets hit is `var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);` afterwards the program runs, but is in a state where nothing happens, because the app never gets initialized properly.

So far I've updated Windows and Visual Studio, installed .NET 6 and .NET 7 as well. I've moved the project from the shared vm folder to the "local" drive and also tried the Blazor WebAssembly template project. My google search skills also yielded no applicable results unfortunately.

I'd appreciate any pointers about what I'm doing wrong or if my setup is just too janky to work... Thanks!

Comment: I have opted to use VS-Code on my actual machine for now, since I just couldn't get it to work. It works pretty much just as well quite frankly, even if I miss some VS features.